# iTunes connect: I can't add new bank account or changing existing?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

Ok I recently closed my bank account and opened a new one that has the same routing number but different account number. Apple tried to make a payment to my account but it was declined because it's closed and I got a notification.

I need to add the new correct number but there is no option to in the Banking/contracts section of iTunes - and I cant change the number on my existing account here:

[image]

What do I do to update the bank account number?

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon the setting by chance.

- "Agreement, Tax, And Banking"
- stay on the "Agreements" page
- click on "Paid Apps"
- You will the see a "Bank Accounts" section with an "edit" button to update your bank details

Not very intuitive, I agree that it should be under the "Banking" page and not in a sub page under "Agreements". Hopefully this saves people a call to developer support to locate the path to changing bank accounts.